# javascript - replace all white spaces with html tags to enclose remaining words

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, whitespace

I have this `<div>`:

```
<div id="myDiv">
orange green, yellow
magenta/23 black: "brown"
</div>
```

I want to replace all white spaces with html tags to enclose remaining words,
for example (`<b>` tags):

```
<div id="myDiv">
<b>orange</b><b>green,</b><b>yellow</b>
<b>magenta/23</b><b>black:</b><b>"brown"</b>
</div>
```

Is there a way do to it in javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way

```
$('#myDiv').html(function (i, html) {
    return '<b>' + html.trim().replace(/(\s+)/g, '</b>$1<b>') + '</b>'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jcghgwj7/)

Comment: My final aim was this http://jsfiddle.net/jcghgwj7/2/ Now, I will try to add different classes via jquery basing every nth child... What do you think about this? Should I use jquery nth child, or there is some variant with your code to do it?

Comment: Upvoting, since you solution was more elegant than mine. :-)

Comment: @user3542686 I think if your markup will strictly follow the given format your approach is ok

Comment: but there is a danger is any one of the line has <> 3 items, then the styling of the rest of the items will be lost - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jcghgwj7/3/

Answer (score 6):

Not tested, bit this should work

```
var myDiv = document.querySelector('#myDiv');

myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML.split(' ').map(function(word){
    return "<b>"+word+"</b>";
}).join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple JS approach:

```
var words = document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML.split(' ');
var output = "";
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    output += '<b>' + words[i] + '</b>';
}

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = output;
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4dnp3t81/

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution. I place the output inside an `xmp` tag so you can see the output.

```js
var myDiv = $("#myDiv").html();
$('#output').html(myDiv.replace(/\s*(.+?)\s/g, "<b>$1</b>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
orange green, yellow
magenta/23 black: "brown"
</div>
<xmp id="output"></xmp>
```